# I need to print the date automatically for the current Month

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-sheets-formula

I need to print the date for the current month in the first column of my google sheet automatically.

I think this can be done through javascript but not sure what code will go in for that? Not good at javascript.
I have a sheet here: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1OyyPKKflKWB3ewLlcCAAkbPE_HMYNnwWUEfP5KOz0o8/edit?usp=sharing

Don't have any code yet.

I want the date for the current month to automatically get inserted in the first column up till the month. For example: If its May, the date should be entered up to 31st and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

delete everything in **A4:A** range and paste this into **A4** cell:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TO_DATE(ROW(
 INDIRECT("A"&DATE(YEAR(A3), MONTH(A3), DAY(A3)+1)):
 INDIRECT("B"&EOMONTH(A3, 0)))))
```

[image: 0]

this will calculate all date ranges between **A3** cell and end of the month of **A3** cell

**A3**: `=DATE(YEAR(TODAY()), MONTH(TODAY()), 1)`

Comment: I tried entering the code in A:4 but it gave me this error : https://storage.googleapis.com/openscreenshot/N/s/B/HJKxpuBsN.png

Comment: @JasdeepSingh in A3 you need to put a date first or: =DATE(YEAR(TODAY()),MONTH(TODAY()),1)